# How to use sslcrtvalidator_program helper in squid on ubuntu

Tags: squid

I have an application that does not support TLS but wants to access another application that requires TLS access with mutual authentication. To bridge the gap I have setup squid in accelerator/reverse-proxy mode using the following configuration:

```
http_access allow all
http_port 80 accel defaultsite=squid

netdb_filename none

cache_peer nginx parent 443 0 no-query originserver tls tls-cafile=/opt/my-squid/certs/ServerCA-chain.pem sslcert=/opt/my-squid/certs/proxy-client.pem name=myAccel
```

This setup works and plain HTTP requests to squid are forwarded over a TLS connection with mutual authentication. However, I would like squid to validate the server certificate of the peer using OCSP. I found the `sslcrtvalidator_program` configuration option and tried to use it together with a shell script:

```
sslcrtvalidator_program cache=0 ttl=1 /opt/my-squid/cert-validator.sh
```

Adding this line leads to squid displaying an error page telling me there is an internal error or a configuration problem that leads to a gateway proxy error. However, I cannot find more information on the issue, the log simply states that the connection failed.

For debugging purposes I am using this simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat >> /tmp/debug.log
```

The file /tmp/debug.log is never written and it seems that the validator is never called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you want to use squid instead of apache or nginx in example? nginx can convert the https request into http without the headache of squid. and iirc, you already have nginx running and want to use squid which does similar things like nginx?

Comment: I'd actually prefer using nginx, but I cannot find a way to do OCSP validation of a certificate of an upstream server with nginx or apache. If you have an idea I would love a hint. I already have an open question for that as well: https://serverfault.com/q/1152662/1073332